# Meaning of an odds ratio in mixed effects logistic regression

Tags: mixed-model, odds-ratio

Pardon my ignorance but I am looking for some statistics help. I ran a mixed effects logistic regression and produced a summary table in R. Because of the nature of the regression type I don't have estimates in my table but instead have odds ratios. I really just want to understand in very simple terms what this ratio is telling me in terms of the relationship between the independent and dependent variable.

Is it true to say that an odds ratio greater than 1 describes a positive relationship between the independent and dependant variables, whereas an odds ratio less than 1 describes a negative relationship? Or am I talking nonsense and this is not the case at all for mixed effects logistic (binary) regression?

Thank you.

Comment: There are a number questions (and answers) on the interpretation of odds ratios on CV, such as [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56793/how-to-interpret-odds-ratio/60978) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34636/interpretation-of-simple-predictions-to-odds-ratios-in-logistic-regression?noredirect=1&lq=1). Are these Q&As helpful?

Comment: Or this one perhaps: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/281809/interpretation-of-odds-ratio-in-logit-models